# How to use async reasonably in koa2

Tags: node.js, ejs, koa, koa2

I am puzzled by two different ways of writing in koa2. My needs are

Get two result from the mysql, and pass them to the `ejs`.

The first way

```
await  mysqlModel.getThePeopleCount() //data from table `people`
.then(async(result) => {
    let countpeople = result[0].peoplecount
    await  mysqlModel.getTheMyInfo() //data from table `myinfo`
    .then(async(result) => {
        await ctx.render('people', {
            myinfo: result[0].name,
            countpeoples:countpeople
        });
    })
})
```

The second way

```
let results1 = await mysqlModel.getThePeopleCount()
let results2 = await mysqlModel.getTheMyInfo()
await ctx.render('people', {
    myinfo: result2[0].name,
    countpeoples:result1[0].peoplecount
});
```

The database is `mysql`, and which one is reasonably way? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to use the second way. The async/await mechanism is meant to replace chaining promises with `.then()`. Here's a good writeup on this (not mine): https://nemethgergely.com/async-function-best-practices/